# Loading views in a specific order

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a specific way I wish to load views and have them do things. Inside my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I load the window:

```
[[self window] makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Now inside the view controller, i need to to ask for location of the user but not immediately. I have a notification observer inside the view controller that does this. I use nsnotification center to do that. In my AppDelegate I post a notification inside the  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

My question is, if I add an observer in my view controller inside awakeFromNib method, will it still be called from the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method when a notification is posted? I do call [[self window] makeKeyAndVisible] first and then post the notification. My fear is what if the awakeFromNib is not called early enough and the observer is not been registered, and I post a notification. That would ruin the experience for a user.

Answer (score 0):

It will be an ongoing problem to have a behavior contained in a view controller which requires notifications to work. iOS may choose to unload the view controller, which would break the system.

My recommendation is to have a persistent data object which handles these notifications. The app delegate can update the data object and the view controller can read from the data object, but it won't require any specific load sequence.